# How would I normalize this nested reducer case?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How would I normalize this nested reducer case?

This code works fine, but I want to normalize it like the redux docs recommend.

```
case POST_COMMENT_SUCCESS:
  //  adds a comment to a post without having to re render.
  // console.log(action.data.commentBody);
  return {
    ...state,
    images: state.images.map((image) => {
      // appends new comment withing images redux state. only if image.id === action.id
      if (image.id === action.id) {
        return {
          ...image,
          comments: [
            ...image.comments,
            {
              comment_body: action.data[0].comment_body,
              user: {
                username: action.data[0].user.username,
              },
            },
          ],
        };
      }
      return image;
    }),
  };
```

*Console.log*

```
  console.log(action.data) //
```

**data structure**

```
{
  "id": 55,
  "comment_body": "ddadada",
  "created_at": "2019-07-24T19:02:38.805Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-07-24T19:02:38.805Z",
  "user_id": 1,
  "image_id": 168,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "googleId": null,
    "username": "*****od",
    "password": "$2b$12$Al888888********O",
    "email": "e*********",
    "created_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-06-23T18:57:17.253Z"
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can use a plugin for redux normalization, or could there be a few things I could change in this reducer case that will normalize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to separate out comments from images and use foreign keys to associate the two.  Although it may work now, it loses scale when that array starts growing to sizes of 1000, etc since the only way to find a particular image is by iterating over an array.

If you use objects where the keys are ids, you eliminate the need to iterate over the array and find and reference the data directly

```
// images store
images: {
  byId: {
    168: {
        commentsById: [55]
    }
  }
}

// comments store
comments: {
  byId: {
    55: {
        "id": 55,
        "comment_body": "ddadada",
        "created_at": "2019-07-24T19:02:38.805Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-07-24T19:02:38.805Z",
        "user_id": 1,
        "image_id": 168,
    }
  }
}
```

also storing user data here other than an id is unneeded as it would be hard to keep that data fresh, you would want a separate store of all the users

Comment: where is imageData coming from ?

Comment: its whatever data you need to store

Comment: its image.comments, would i need to do something like .`...image, ...image.comments`

Comment: sure, you can put any necessary data there, the main point was that its an object, with keys of unique ids

Comment: could you please update the answer that accommodates my existing code. So i can accept as answer. :)

Comment: i updated the code, you would also want to follow a similar format for `users`, but you would prolly want to not return sensitive data from an api even if its encrypted